# Java / Gradle - building a .jar file from .class files

Tags: java, class, gradle, jar

I'm a newbie to Gradle. I'm tasked with writing a Gradle script / task that takes a bunch of precompiled .class and .properties files in a given directory (and all subdirectories thereof) and creating a single .jar file from them, manifest and all.

For example, if I were using Ant .xml script, I might do something like the following:

```
<target name="test" description="Build test.jar">
    <exec dir="${testdir}" executable="cmd.exe " os="Windows 10">
        <arg line="/c mkdir lib" />
    </exec>
    <jar destfile="${libdir}/test.jar">
        <fileset dir="${testdir}/classes">
            <include name="**/*.class" />
            <include name="**/*.properties" />
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>
```

But I have no idea how to do something similar in Gradle. Would appreciate any help.

Edit: Running Gradle v.2.14.1, Groovy v.2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

May be this one will be helpful.
Save in `build.gradle` and run by `gradle zip`

```
task zip(type: Zip) {
    from 'app/classes'
    include '**/*.class'
    into('libdir/packed.zip') {
    }
}
```

Source https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm still having trouble though because what I'm tasked with is something very specific -- I'm not supposed to compile anything myself, but rather take a number of .class and / or .properties files and just build a .jar file from them. It looks like there is a jar task that I could use for this, but I'm not sure how to specify the source directories (where the .class files reside) as well as the destination directory (where the .jar file should be created).